# How to get an image link in site content and structure on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, web-part

I want to change the picture in one sub site by using an address link. However, when I go to site content and structure to select the picture I want, I can't get the address link for the picture. I know I can use "change picture from SharePoint, computer and address", but I don't understand why I cannot change picture from address. How can I get the address link on site content and structure?

Answer (score 1):

Another option to Ankit's suggestion is to open up the image library in a separate browser tab/window. This is a good way to go if you need to get the address of multiple images.

Typically you would click on 'View all site content' or 'Site contents' (or similar) and in the list of libraries/lists find the image library containing the image(s) you want to link to.

Once the library is open, navigate to the actual image and when the properties open you can right-click on the image's name and select *Copy shortcut*. This will copy the address of the image.

If you then need to also copy other addresses, you 'close' the image properties screen and navigate to/select the next image in your image library and follow the same process again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just Hover over the image and do a right click and you should see a option as properties. Once you click on properties, you can always see the URL of the Image and can copy from there. Other option is to right click on image and click on Copy Shortcut.

Comment: Hi, there are two options which are view properties and edit properties. I clicked into both but nothing come out.

Comment: open in some other browser...you should see the properties.